# Unable to count sort more than eight elements

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

Here is my code. While choosing values, if I try to put 9 values it dumps garbage value. It has happened while doing quick sort as well

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
void printArray(int* A, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int maximum(int A[],int n) {
    int i, max = A[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (A[i] > max) {
            max = A[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void countSort(int A[], int n) {  
    int i, max = maximum(A, n);
    int count[max + 1], B[n];

    for (i = 0; i < max + 1; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < max + 1; i++) {
        count[A[i]]++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        B[--count[A[i]]] = A[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = B[i];
    }
}
 
int main(){
    int A[] = {1, 4, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 7};
    int n = 9;
    printArray(A, n); // Printing the array before sorting
    countSort(A, n);  // Function to sort the array
    printArray(A, n); // Printing the array before sorting

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So go ahead and debug it. Run your program in a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the program execution and variable values. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `for(i=0;i<max+1;i++) count[A[i]]++;` The end index is wrong. Should be `n` not `max+1`. Should be able to find that yourself with basic debugging.

Comment: You should have debugged this program by printing the contents of the relevant arrays after each loop in `countSort` to see if the loop accomplished what you intended, or by viewing the arrays in a debugger, after each loop. At the very least, that would have revealed exactly where in the program something went wrong. Do not debug by posting to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses the wrong limit:

```
    for(i=0;i<max+1;i++) {
        count[A[i]]++;
    }
```

It effectively iterates through the elements of `A`, which has `n` elements, not `max+1`.